# Weierstrass substitution for solving trigonometric eqations

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve a set of equations of a parallel robot [image]. The equations can be writen as $x(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$

$y(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$  so to solve the equation I used  Weierstrass substitution: $\sin(\theta)=2T/(1+T^2)$,
$\cos(\theta)=(1-T^2)/(1+T^2)$ and I got a polynomial of 6th degree (which is what should happen because a planar robot each joint has 2 DOF). Now I want to solve numericly to find the solution, I know that $[-1, 1]$ is where $\sin (\theta)$ changes, but $\cos(\theta)$ is from $(-\infty +\infty])$. can I solve the equation only on the interval $[-1, 1]$? how will i know the sign of $\cos(\theta)$?
Thanks

Comment: Could you post the equation you need to solve ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I had no idea how  to write theta.

Comment: It won't help to post the equation, it has huge coefficients that have in them a parameter that needs to be given 
(the length of the links)